# Настроить положение футера

Tags: css3, html

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему перевернулись все сроки, кроме заголовков? И как перевернуть его полностью?

http://jsfiddle.net/mynyhLk7/6/

**Обновление**

Положение, которого добиваюсь: вертикальное, когда все пункты футера идут снизу. Что касается верстки - я только начала изучать, но буду признательна, если укажете на конкретные ошибки.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, ты зачем их белыми сделал? Я их еле нашёл.
Во-вторых, как раз наоборот - перевернулись только заголовки.
В-третьих, кого "его" надо перевернуть полностью?
В-четвёртых, вёрстка неправильная, разумеется будет глючить.

Comment: Положение которого добиваюсь: вертикальное, когда все пункты футера идут снизу. Что касается верстки - я только начала изучать, но буду признательна, если  укажете на конкретные ошибки. Спасибо